# Reading to JSON URLs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, getjson

I need to read *two* JSON URLs with jQuery, mangle them together and then proceed updating my UI from the JSON data.

With the two URLs in `URLA` and `URLB` and a global variable `globalDataA` I tried:

```
function useBothData(dataB) {
   // use dataB and globalDataA
};

function useDataA (data) {
    globalDataA = data
    $.getJSON (URLB, useBothData);
};

$.getJSON (URLA, useDataA);
```

The idea is that after loading the 1st URL I load the 2nd and then work with them. However this does never seem to return. (I get the Brwoser warning "Script takes too long".)

How can I arrange jQuery's `getJSON` calls for the two URLs (and their success functions), so that I can then use their data in finally *one* function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the callback function of getJSON

```
$.getJSON(URLA, useDataA, function(dataB) {
  //useBothData = globalDataA + dataB

  $.getJSON(URLB, useBothData, function(result) {
    //do more stuff
  })
});
```

Comment: I think, that's what I tried (see my question - I just defined the callbacks as named functions). - and  somehow it didn't work. But I tried it again and now it _does_ work! So you are certainly right. :-)

Comment: @halloleo I think that the problem was that the getJSON function accepts 3 parameters. The URL, the data that you are sending to the server (like a post), and last the callback function. And you were passing only Url and function. Keep in mind that if you don't need to send the data to the server, you can put NULL in the second param
$.GetJSON (URLA, null, function (data)